# return data in php for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

let's get the output of a loop in a variable, i am trying to return data in a for loop. Here is the code:

```
<?php
for($i=0,$j=0; $i<=10, $j<=10; $i++,$j++){
    $data = "$i and $j<br>";
    return $data;
}
echo $data;
?>
```

Here is the code http://codepad.org/qqnGdjS7 
so, how return data in php for loop, so there is ways to use loop data outside of the loop!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$data = '';
for($i=0,$j=0; $i<=10, $j<=10; $i++,$j++){
    $data .= "$i and $j<br/>";
}
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

is it really the loop you want ? 1 1, 2 2, 3 3 ?
to have 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, ... do:

```
$data = '';
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<=10; $j++){
        $data .= "$i and $j<br/>";
    }
}
echo $data;
```